# How to keep aspect ratio of images pasted from links using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, image, resize, aspect-ratio

I need help locking the aspect ratio of images in a VBA code which pastes into an excel file images from links using information in specific cells.

What I would like to know is how to lock the aspect ratio of these pasted images.
I have tried to change things but haven't been able to succeed in keeping the aspect ratio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks,
Peter

```
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
On Error Resume Next
Dim Plage As Range
Dim p As Object, t As Double, l As Double, w As Double, h As Double
Set Plage = Selection

lig = Plage.Cells(1).Row
col = Plage.Cells(1).Column

nbcel = 0
For Each cell In Plage
    If cell.Value <> "" Then nbcel = nbcel + 1
Next cell

posColstr = InputBox("En quelle colonne voulez-vous inserer vos photos (1, 2, 3...)?", "Colonne", 1)
posCol = CInt(posColstr)
If posCol = 0 Then posCol = 1

For i = 0 To nbcel - 1
    Matiere = Cells(i + lig, col).Value
    Cells(i + lig, posCol).Activate
    With Cells(i + lig, posCol)
        t = .Top
        l = .Left
        w = .Width
        h = .Height
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:="https://websiteimagelink.com/" & Matiere & ".null.null.null.null.null.jpg", linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Top:=t, Left:=l, Width:=70, Height:=50
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count).Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    
    
Next i
```

Comment: You're not using `w` or `h`?

Comment: no, the script uses .Height:=70 and Width:=50 and works as it is but only the images sizes to those dimensions, and the images aren't all to that aspect ratio so they come out warped sometimes

Comment: I tried with Height:=h and Width:=w but that only makes the pictures the size of the cell instead of their original aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can do it.

Edited to show how it fits in your code.

```vb
Sub InsertPics()

    Const MAX_WIDTH As Long = 100   'max picture width
    Const MAX_HEIGHT As Long = 100  'max height
    
    Dim Plage As Range, url, rngPic As Range
    Dim p As Object, t As Double, l As Double, w As Double, h As Double
    
    Set Plage = Selection
    
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    On Error Resume Next
    
    posColstr = InputBox("En quelle colonne voulez-vous inserer vos photos (1, 2, 3...)?", "Colonne", 1)
    posCol = CInt(posColstr)
    If posCol = 0 Then posCol = 1
    
    For Each c In Plage.Cells         'loop over user selection
        Matiere = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(Matiere) > 0 Then      'if cell has a value...
            url = "https://websiteimagelink.com/" & Matiere & ".null.null.null.null.null.jpg"
            Set rngPic = c.EntireRow.Cells(posCol)
            InsertResizePic rngPic, url, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT 'or rngpic.Width, rngpic.Height
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


'Insert a shape from path `pth`, positioned at cell `c`: resize so dimensions do
'   not exceed `maxWidth` or `maxHeight`
Sub InsertResizePic(c As Range, pth As String, maxWidth As Long, maxHeight As Long)
    
    Dim fW, fH, shp
    
    Set shp = c.Parent.Pictures.Insert(Filename:=pth)
    With shp
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue 'lock relative h/w
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .Top = c.Top
        .Left = c.Left
    
        fW = .Width / maxWidth    'dimensions relative to max allowed
        fH = .Height / maxHeight
        
        If fW > 1 Or fH > 1 Then      'is it too wide or too tall?
            If fW >= fH Then
                .Width = .Width / fW    'more too wide than too tall: shrink width
            Else
                .Height = .Height / fH  'shrink height
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, would you have any suggestions on how to integrate it into the existing script?

I have tried to use LockAspectRatio in the following line but haven't been able to make it work.
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:="https://websiteimagelink.com/" & Matiere & ".null.null.null.null.null.jpg", linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Top:=t, Left:=l, Width:=70, Height:=50